# App crashes due to no call to super.OnCreate() even when call is present in ListFragment

Tags: java, android, android-support-library

My app crashes with the SuperNotCalledException.
I have already called `super.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);` in `OnCreate()`. Here's my code.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get max available VM memory, exceeding this amount will throw an
    // OutOfMemory exception. Stored in kilobytes as LruCache takes an
    // int in its constructor.
    final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);

    // Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
    final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

    mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
        @Override
        protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
            // The cache size will be measured in kilobytes rather than
            // number of items.
            return bitmap.getByteCount() / 1024;
        }
    };

}
```

The app crashes with the following stacktrace.
`11-07 12:56:37.807  15516-15516/com.laer.easycast D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM<
11-07 12:56:37.817  15516-15516/com.laer.easycast E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.laer.easycast, PID: 15516
    android.support.v4.app.SuperNotCalledException: Fragment ImagePane{64e8db70 id=0x7f090001} did not call through to super.onCreate()`

Any idea what's wrong with it? I've tried hard...

Comment: what is the class declaration?

Comment: this looks like it could be that your activity did not call super.onCreate()

Comment: Here's the link to the activity declaration. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6tlxyJqDb18SVptMzMxUDZxSjA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: `Fragment ImagePane` did not call `super.onCreate()` in its `onCreate()` - is this code from your `ImagePane`?

Comment: @laalto The code posted above in the question is from ImagePane. The code in the link is my IDE's screenshot.

Comment: @Jim The activity does most definitely call `super.OnCreate();` Check out my earlier comment.

Comment: Ok - does `ImagePane` extend some class that overrides `onCreate()` but does not call `super.onCreate()`?

Comment: `ImagePane extends ListFragment` Now I'm not sure if `ListFragment` class calls `super();` This might be it... Any ideas?

Comment: the error says "ImagePane" does not call super.onCreate()...

Comment: @Jim Yes,but my code definitely calls it. So confusing!!

Comment: I meant that your link doesn't show that, and the code you posted does not show it either... post more code...

Comment: @Jim The code posted above has `super.OnCreate()` statement. It's from the `ListFragment`.

Comment: how many times do you want someone to ask you to post more code?? if you know that you've posted enough, then you would have already solved the problem...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64474/discussion-between-boggartfly-and-jim).

Comment: I face the same issue. Please help